# How to get size in Bytes of textarea value

Tags: javascript, size, textarea, byte

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Count bytes in textarea using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848462/count-bytes-in-textarea-using-javascript)

Hello everyone.

I am trying to get the size in bytes of text inside textarea.

by using the following code:

```
function getSize(obj)
{
    return (document.getElementById(obj).value.length);
}
```

I get the number of chars. (\n count as one char, no Idea why).

anyway, how can I get the size in bytes of text inside textarea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size in bytes of a text snippet depends on the encoding which can be arbitrary (overridden by the user agent).

Measuring regular text in bytes makes sense only if the encoding is known. For example, ASCII text is 1 byte per char. <strike>Unicode</strike> UTF-16LE has 2 bytes. UTF-8 is a whole different story, things can span from 1 byte to 4 bytes.

Comment: Actually, strings in JS are stored in UTF-16 internally. At least, in FF.

Comment: `Unicode has 2 bytes` - **NO.** [Unicode is not an encoding.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951722/) But, good point about the size depending on the encoding.

Comment: I want to get the size in bytes of ANSI encoding.

Comment: @Ron: The size in bytes of ANSI encoding equals to the number of chars.

Comment: @Saul, no it doest because \n should be 2 bytes but the .length function counts it as one. (\n as new line).

Comment: Because it's not, it's translated to a newline character, which is only 1 byte

Comment: @M28, if u make new like in text file (ANSI encoded) and save the file, the size will be 2 bytes...

Comment: @Ron: By standard, every ANSI character **is** 1 byte long. Even the newline `\n`. The fact of it having a 2-character visual representation does not mean an actual newline takes up 2 bytes in memory.

Comment: @Ron In windows, newlines are \r\n (or \n\r, I don't remember). In other systems, it's just \n

Comment: @M28: *nix uses `\n` and on Apple it's `\r`. Windows developers wanted to have the best of both worlds but ended up in creating a new headache.