# GetByteCount for UTF8 string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#

I use this C# code to find out how many bytes my string has:

```
private void CalculateBytes(string text)
{
    string s = Convert.ToString(text);
    int len = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(s);
}
```

But I don't know how to do the same thing in javascript. How can I calculate the bytes of my string in javascript?

**UPDATE:**

TextEncoder() and Buffer are not working. I get an error message:

> "Error": {
>               "Error": "JavascriptException",
>               "Message": "JavascriptException",
>               "StackTrace": "ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined\n    at getBinarySize (BFD0A-main.js:763:5)\n    at handlers.GetBytesFromText (BFD0A-main.js:756:24)\n    at Object.invokeFunction (Script:116:33)"
>           }

```
var text = "Text"; 
var bytes = (new TextEncoder().encode(text)).length;

Buffer.byteLength(text, 'utf8'))
```

I use Microsoft PlayFab Cloud Script: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/automation/cloudscript/quickstart

Comment: @mbojko that does not provide the information the OP is asking for.

Comment: To do this, it would be necessary to construct a list of the UTF-8 code sequences from the UTF-16 sequence in the string, explicitly detecting surrogate UTF-16 pairs along the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [TextEncoder.Encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder/encode) function and then get the length of that.

```js
var text = "Text"; 
var bytes = (new TextEncoder().encode(text)).length;
document.write("Number of bytes: " + bytes);
```

As pointing out in the comments you'll need a [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-encoding-polyfill) for this to work in IE11 or Edge.

**Update:**
Alternative solution found from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5015930/2098773

```js
function getUTF8Length(string) {
    var utf8length = 0;
    for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {
        var c = string.charCodeAt(n);
        if (c < 128) {
            utf8length++;
        }
        else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
            utf8length = utf8length+2;
        }
        else {
            utf8length = utf8length+3;
        }
    }
    return utf8length;
 }
 
 document.write(getUTF8Length("Test"));
```

Comment: This is correct though it's unsupported in Edge and IE11.

Comment: You'll need to [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-encoding-polyfill) for MS browsers.

Comment: It's not working. I get this error message: "Error": {
            "Error": "JavascriptException",
            "Message": "JavascriptException",
            "StackTrace": "ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined\n    at GetStringBytes (BFD0A-main.js:769:17)\n    at handlers.GetBytesFromText (BFD0A-main.js:755:26)\n    at Object.invokeFunction (Script:116:33)"
        }

Comment: @Tobey60 I've updated the solution with a snippet found from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5015930/2098773